# Arduino IDE for ESP32: Compilation Error: Exist status 255

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

**Problem:**

I have a ESP32 and I've been trying to flash it with the Arduino IDE, however it's been giving me Python error messages :/ when I'm trying C/C++ code to flash the Arduino.

**Question:**

How can I setup the board below so I can flashi it with C/C++ from the Arduino IDE?

**Error Message:**

```
  [6909] Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/wm/_tds7_0s6_j9587rbm54nfv00000gn/T/_MEIli4AzL/libpython3.8.dylib': dlopen: dlopen(/var/folders/wm/_tds7_0s6_j9587rbm54nfv00000gn/T/_MEIli4AzL/libpython3.8.dylib, 10): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /var/folders/wm/_tds7_0s6_j9587rbm54nfv00000gn/T/_MEIli4AzL/libintl.8.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 11.0)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
  in /var/folders/wm/_tds7_0s6_j9587rbm54nfv00000gn/T/_MEIli4AzL/libintl.8.dylib

  exit status 255

  Compilation error: exit status 255
```

**ESP32:**

[image]

**References Used/Due Diligence:**

- [Installing the ESP32 Board in Arduino IDE (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux)](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/installing-the-esp32-board-in-arduino-ide-windows-instructions/)
- [Getting Started with the ESP32 Development Board](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/getting-started-with-esp32/)
- [ESP32 Bluetooth Classic with Arduino IDE – Getting Started](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-bluetooth-classic-arduino-ide/)

**Version Numbers:**

- MAC OS Version: macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6
- Arduino Version: Version 2.0.4-nightly-20230119 CLI Version: 0.29.0

Comment: The error message says "...Mac OS X 11.0...". Is that the version of OS X you are using? Can you tell us what version of the IDE you are using?

Comment: Appended into the Question: `macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6`; `Arduino Version: Version 2.0.4-nightly-20230119` and `CLI Version: 0.29.0`

Comment: @VE7JRO I've updated the question with the version numbers.

Comment: And what do you conclude? The library was built for 11.0 but you have 10.13... Did you try to use a version of the Arduino IDE for _your_ OS?

Comment: You might want to re-read the referenced tutorials. _Disclaimer: I don't have a Mac and no ESP32 at hand, but know a bit about general computer science and used the Arduino IDE for different targets._

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Mac but I am working on Linux and I also had issues with Arduino IDE v2 (in the past). Because of this I'm still using IDE v1 with no issues and that's my suggestion: try older version of the IDE on your mac, you can still download it. If it won't work you can turn to PlatformIO or VSCode IDEs.